# Displaying two glyphicons in a single td cell

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I have a requirement where I need to display two glyphicons in a single td cell. But the second one is overriding the first time.

In the below code :

I am sending two styles which contains gyphicons in the code :

```
 table.setHeaderStyles("weekdays", i - daysBefore, " dayinfo glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" + glyphicon-exclamation-sign);
```

Here is how it displays as HTML

```
<td class="v-table-cell-content v-table-cell-content- dayinfo glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="width: 26px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: center; width: 26px;">Fri</div></td>
```

Here is the CSS for styles:

```
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: #991F3D !important;
    margin-bottom: -7px !important;
    float: right;
}

.glyphicon-info-sign:before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" !important;
    font-size: 9px !important;
    color: #1F6689 !important;
    margin-bottom: -7px !important;
    float: left;
}
```

Here the second style is overriding the first one. 
But I want both the styles to get displayed.

Is there any way to do that? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `:after` instead of `:before` for the second selector.

Comment: @Koen Thank you for the reply. But it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple unicode characters into one pseudo element.

```css
td:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 20px;
  content: "\e089\e088";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use both `:before` and `:after` if you want to apply different style to them.

```css
td:before,
td:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

td:before {
  content: "\e089";
  color: green;
}

td:after {
  content: "\e088";
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```